# How do see whether Journey Builder is taking too long?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

We are using SFMC due to requiring a HIPAA compliant CRM, but are otherwise much smaller (for now...) than a typical SFMC user. We need to send at most hundreds of emails a day.

We are currently running several automated onboarding and abandoned cart style Journeys using the same base Data Extension `account` as the entry source (not an API event).

This is for simplicity. I understand I could use an automation to create a sendable data extension for each journey, applying the required filter logic. Instead, I just use `account` and configure the entry logic directly in Journey Builder.

For each new journey I make like this, I get this warning

> You have selected a data source that is already used for one or more other journeys. Using the same data extension for multiple journeys will impact the performance of each journey using this source because the data will be processed separately by each journey. To reduce this risk, you should schedule different entry times for each of the journeys using the same source or consider using separate data extensions for each journey.

I understand the rational here, but at our scale this feels like not an issue. But, I don't know where I'd look to find this out. If there *was* an issue here, or as we grow and have more users coming in per hour, what would happen if this became a problem? Would users just get the emails a little later (fine) or would emails end up not being sent (a problem).

Any ideas welcome, I'm a newbie with SFMC.

Comment: Have you tested you multiple journeys tied to the same DE use case?  It sounds complicated and less than optimal support wise.  But if you have to separate automations with queries attached to the same Data Extension but different Journey activities they should only fire into their respective journeys.  It shouldn't impact timing much.